# What kind of sand should I use for a sandbox?

Tags: outdoor, play-structures

What type of Sand is normally used for Sandboxes? I've heard some people love Masonry sand because it clean of small pebbles. Other like Concrete sand because it packs well.

Comment: Get the stuff labeled PLAY SAND.

Comment: The sandbox is 64 sq ft and would like the sand 8 to 10 inches deep. So roughly 2 cubic yards.I can only find washed play sand in bags of .5 cu ft.  At $3 a bag, I hoping to save some money and buy from a landscaping company. Just wondering if there was a specific type of sand commonly used.

Comment: landscaping companies often sell Play Sand by the cubic yard.

Answer (score 6):

Industrial sand often contains fine silica dust and really shouldn't be used for sandboxes, as that dust can be inhaled, [which isn't good for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis).

Dust-free sand (Such as [Sakrete play sand](http://www.sakrete.com/products/detail.cfm/prod_alias/Natural-Play-Sand)) or non-silica sand (Such as [Sandtastik](http://www.sandtastik.com/100-sand)) would be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Play sand or table sand are the only types you should use, for safety reasons. Other aggregates are not intended to be used by children who tend to eat the stuff, accidentally or intentionally. Though probably safe, aggregate sands are not produced or cleaned and tested with ingestion in mind. They don't just go the beach and get the sand and label it. It does go through some processing and can be contaminated by other products in the quarry or processing plant. It's best to err on the side of caution and just get the proper sand.